# Speed up Cassandra Keyspace Schema craetion

Tags: cassandra

I have to import Cassandra schema into a new Keyspace. The schema consists of about 6 'Create Table' requests each followed by about 3-4 'Create Index' commands.

I have a cql file which has this  schema. I apply the schema using the 'cqlsh -f ' command with the --request-timeout=60 parameter passed. Without the request-timeout parameter, the table creation times out.

I wanted to know the average time it would take to create such a schema.For now this process takes about 10-15 minutes which I think is too long. Is there  any way that we could reduce the time taken to add a  schema.

Memory available in the cluster -

`root@cassandra-0:~# free -m

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          16042        9903         277         171        5861        5833
Swap:             0           0           0`

Comment: How big is your cluster? And what its topology?

Comment: It's a single node cluster deployed on Kubernetes using the docker image present at https://hub.docker.com/r/_/cassandra/

Comment: That's really strange, unfortunately I can't say much - try to look into `system.log` to check what happens inside when the tables are created.

Comment: No errors in the system.log file. Everything seems to be normal.